# Debian Squeeze not whole of package contents installed

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

When I do `apt-get install usb-modeswitch-data`, not all of it's contents are installed under `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d`. I looked inside package and wasn't able to understand how could it be -- there were no special filtering of package contents visible to me.

I'm using Debian Squeeze and package in question is `usb-modeswitch-data:20100826-1+squeeze0`.

Can somebody explain this effect?

Answer (score 1):

Things inside /etc won't get override by default, I think you might removed stuff in `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d` "accidentally",

Looks like you fixed the problem already, but next time try use `dpkg -L usb-modeswitch-data usb-modeswitch` to see if these files belong to that package and see if it exists or not

Answer (score 0):

You can list the content of the debian packages like this :

- installed packages : `dpkg -L package_name`
- not installed packages `apt-file list package_name`

Comment: Sorry, not quite understand how it answers my question :) Package is reported as installed by dpkg/apt, it's just that not all of it's files are installed.

Answer (score 0):

I must take my question back, after I did `dpkg --purge usb-modeswitch-data usb-modeswitch` and then `apt-get install usb-modeswitch-data`, all of the package contents were installed into proper place.

Must be some glitch on dpkg side or, more probably, me overlooking something.